# angular4 form saving exception

Tags: forms, angular, save

hi every body i am using angular 4 , when i save form in deployment mode, i get the error down , and when i save the same form in development mode i don't get the exception.

my form code products-form.component.ts :

```ts
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {AdminService} from "../../../services/admin.service";
import {HttpService} from "../../../../http.service";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";
import {Http, Response, Headers,RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {BusyModule} from 'angular2-busy';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';
import {DiscardPopUpComponent} from '../../../../discard-pop-up/discard-pop-up.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-products-form',
  templateUrl: './products-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductsFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

   product:any = {'needTransformer':'Yes',
    'power':'',
    'cct':'',
    'cri':'',
    'lightSource':'',
     'country':'',
     'category':{},
      'productionCompany':{},
      'finish':{}};
   discardPopUpTitle:string = "Discard Changes";
   discardPopUpContent:string="Are you Sure you want to discard changes and exit to products table ?";
   selectedPopUpOption:string;
   discardDialog:DiscardPopUpComponent;
   showPopUp = false;
   popUpresult = false;
   isFormDirty:boolean=false;
   companies: string[] =[];
   companiesSubscription: Subscription;
   finishes: string[] = [];
   finishesSubscription: Subscription;

   categories: string[] = [];
   categoriesSubscription: Subscription;

   lightSources: string[] = [];
   lightSourcesSubscription: Subscription;

   countries: string[] = [];
   countriesSubscription: Subscription;

   routeSubscritpion: Subscription;

   selectedCategory: string;
   selectedFinish: string;
   selectedProductionCompany: string;
   selectedLightSource: string;
   selectedCountry: string;
   selectedTransformerNeeded: string;
   isEdit: boolean = false;
   isShow: boolean = false;
   message: string;

  @ViewChild('mainImage')  mainImage: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('diemsnions')  diemsnions: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('effects')  effects: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('pdf')  pdf: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('categoryEl') categoryEl: ElementRef;

  busy: any;
  isSuccess: boolean = false;
  currentCode: string;
  constructor(private httpService:HttpService, private adminService: AdminService, private http: Http, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,public dialog: MdDialog) {
    console.log(dialog);
    this.discardDialog = new DiscardPopUpComponent();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.busy = true;
    this.routeSubscritpion = this.route.params.subscribe(param => {
      let code = param['code'];
      if(code != undefined)
        this.httpService.getProductDataByCode(code).subscribe(
        (data:any)=> {
         this.product=data;
         this.currentCode = data.code;
         this.isEdit = true;
         this.selectedCategory = data.category.name;
         this.selectedFinish = data.finish.name;
         this.selectedCountry = data.country;
         this.selectedProductionCompany = data.productionCompany.name;
         this.selectedLightSource = data.lightSource;
         this.selectedTransformerNeeded = data.transformerNeeded;
         // this.categoryEl.nativeElement.value = data.category.name;
      },
      (err)  => console.error(err+"<-------------"),
        () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
      );


    });

    this.companiesSubscription = this.httpService.getAllCompanies().subscribe(
      (data:any)=> {
        data.forEach((entry)=> {
          this.companies.push(entry.name);
        });
        if(this.companies.length > 0)
          this.product.productionCompany = this.companies[0];
      },
      (err)  => console.error(err+"<-------------"),
      () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
    );

    this.categoriesSubscription = this.httpService.getAllCategories().subscribe(
      (data:any)=> {
        data.forEach((entry)=> {
          this.categories.push(entry.name);
        });
        if(this.categories.length > 0)
          this.product.category = this.categories[0];
      },
        (err)  => console.error(err+"<-------------"),
        () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
    );

    this.finishesSubscription = this.httpService.getAllFinishes().subscribe(
      (data:any)=> {
        data.forEach((entry)=> {
          this.finishes.push(entry.name);
        });
        if(this.finishes.length > 0)
          this.product.finish = this.finishes[0];
      },
        (err)  => console.error(err+"<-------------"),
        () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
    );

    this.lightSourcesSubscription = this.httpService.getAllLightSources().subscribe(
      (data:any)=> {
        this.lightSources = data;
        if(this.lightSources.length > 0)
          this.product.lightSource = this.lightSources[0];
      },
      (err)  => console.error(err+"<-------------"),
      () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
    );

    this.httpService.getAllCountries().subscribe(
      (data:any)=> {
        this.countries = data;
        if(this.countries.length > 0)
          this.product.country = this.countries[0];
      },
      (err)  => console.error(err+"<-------------"),
      () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
    );
  }

readUrl(event,url) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event) => {
      var target:FileReader=<FileReader>event.target;
      this.product[url] = target.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
}

  formatStrings(str)
  {
    str=str.replace(/\s/g, '');
    str=str.replace(/,/g, '');
    str=str.toUpperCase();
    return str
  }

  onSubmit(form:NgForm)
  {
    var values=form.value;
    let parent=this;

    let obj={
      name:values.name,
      description:values.description,
      code:values.code,
      category:{
        name:values.categories
      },
      productionCompany:{
        name:values.productionCompany
      },
      finish:{
        name:values.finish
      },
      transformerNeeded:values.transformerNeeded,
      power:values.power,
      cct:values.cct,
      cri:values.cri,
      ik: values.ik,
      ip: values.ip,
      luminous: values.luminous,
      optic: values.optic,
      lightSource:values.lightSource,
      country:values.productionContry,
      effictImagePath:'',
      normalImagePath:'',
      detailsImagePath:'',
      catalogPath:''

    };


    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,'Authorization': JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))['token']});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    if(!this.isEdit) {


      this.busy = this.http.post('http://levelskw.com/products/', JSON.stringify(obj), options).subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          this.product=obj;
          this.currentCode = obj.code;
          this.isEdit = true;
          this.selectedCategory = obj.category.name;
          this.selectedFinish = obj.finish.name;
          this.selectedCountry = obj.country;
          this.selectedProductionCompany = obj.productionCompany.name;
          this.selectedLightSource = obj.lightSource;
          this.selectedTransformerNeeded = obj.transformerNeeded;

          this.isSuccess = true;
          this.message="Success";
          parent.upload(obj.code)
        },
        (err) => {
          this.isSuccess = false;
          this.message=JSON.parse(err._body).msg;
          this.isShow = true;
          let timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            this.isShow = false;
          }, 5000);
        },
        () => console.log("")
      );
    } else {
      this.busy = this.http.put('http://levelskw.com/products/'+this.currentCode, JSON.stringify(obj), options).subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          this.isSuccess = true;
          this.message="Success";
          parent.upload(this.currentCode);

        },
        (err) =>{
          this.isSuccess = false;
          this.message=JSON.parse(err._body).msg;
          this.isShow = true;
          let timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            this.isShow = false;
          }, 5000);
        },
        () => console.log("")
      );
    }


    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.isFormDirty = false;
    this.companiesSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.finishesSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.lightSourcesSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  changeFinish(finish) {
    this.product.finish = finish;
    console.log(this.product);
  }

  makeFileRequest(url:string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let mainImageEl: HTMLInputElement = this.mainImage.nativeElement;
      let formData = new FormData();
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if (mainImageEl.files.length > 0)
        formData.append("normalImagePath", mainImageEl.files.item(0), mainImageEl.files.item(0).name);

      let diemsnionsEl: HTMLInputElement = this.diemsnions.nativeElement;
      if (diemsnionsEl.files.length > 0)
        formData.append("detailsImagePath", diemsnionsEl.files.item(0), diemsnionsEl.files.item(0).name);

      let effectsEl: HTMLInputElement = this.effects.nativeElement;
      if (effectsEl.files.length > 0)
        formData.append("effictImagePath", effectsEl.files.item(0), effectsEl.files.item(0).name);

      let pdfEl: HTMLInputElement = this.pdf.nativeElement;
      if (pdfEl.files.length > 0)
        formData.append("catalogPath", pdfEl.files.item(0), pdfEl.files.item(0).name);

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
          if (xhr.status == 200) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
          } else {
            reject(xhr.response);
          }
        }
      };


      xhr.open("POST", url, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))['token']);
      xhr.send(formData);
    });
  }
  upload(code: string) {
    this.busy = this.makeFileRequest("http://levelskw.com/products/upload/"+code).then((result) => {
      this.isShow = true;
      let timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        this.isShow = false;
      }, 5000);
    }, (error) => {
      this.isShow = true;
      let timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        this.isShow = false;
      }, 5000);
    });

  }

  cancel() {
        this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }


      openDialog() {
        this.showPopUp=true;
        this.discardDialog.show();
  }

  takePopUpEvent(isPopUpValueConfermed:boolean){
    this.popUpresult = isPopUpValueConfermed;

    if(this.popUpresult){
      this.cancel() ;
    }else{
      this.showPopUp=false;
    }
  }

  onChange(form:NgForm){
    console.log(form);
      this.isFormDirty = true;
  }

}
```

my HTML code products-form.component.html :

```html
<app-popup [isShow]="isShow" [message]="message" [isSuccess]="isSuccess"></app-popup>

<div [ngBusy]="busy"></div>
  <div class="main-container">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
        <app-discard-pop-up [showPopUp]="showPopUp" [popUpTitle]="discardPopUpTitle" [popUpContent]="discardPopUpContent" (isConfermed)="takePopUpEvent($event)" ></app-discard-pop-up>
    <div fxLayout="column"  fxLayoutGap="15px">
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="29px">
        <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="20px">
          <div fxLayout="column" class='titleSection'>
            <div class="header"><div class='header-label'>Header</div></div>
            <div class='title'><input type="text" placeholder="Code" name="code" [(ngModel)]="product.code" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" /></div>
            <div class='title'><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="product.name" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" /></div>
            <div class="description"><textarea placeholder="Description" name="description" [(ngModel)]="product.description" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" ></textarea></div>
          </div>
          <div fxLayout="column" class="loadSection">
            <div class="header"><div class='header-label'>Files</div></div>
            <div fxLayout="column" class="img-section" fxLayoutGap="2px">
              <div class="img-lable">Main image</div>
              <div class="img-btn">
                <button fxLayoutAlign="center center">Upload</button>
                <img class="img-view" [src]="product.normalImagePath" />
                <input type="file" (change)="readUrl($event,'normalImagePath')"  #mainImage (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="column" class="img-section" fxLayoutGap="2px">
              <div class="img-lable">Dimensions</div>
              <div class="img-btn">
                <button fxLayoutAlign="center center">Upload</button>
                <img class="img-view" [src]="product.detailsImagePath" />
                <input type="file" (change)="readUrl($event,'detailsImagePath')" #diemsnions (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="column" class="img-section" fxLayoutGap="2px">
              <div class="img-lable">Effects</div>
              <div class="img-btn">
                <button fxLayoutAlign="center center">Upload</button>
                <img class="img-view" [src]="product.effictImagePath" />
                <input type="file" (change)="readUrl($event,'effictImagePath')" #effects (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="column" class="img-section" fxLayoutGap="2px">
              <div class="img-lable">PDF</div>
              <div class="img-btn">
                <button fxLayoutAlign="center center">Upload</button>
                <img class="img-view" src="../../../../assets/Icons/pdf.png" />
                <input type="file"  #pdf (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="column" class="details" fxLayoutGap="10px">
          <div class="header"><div class='header-label'>Related Products</div></div>
          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Category</div>
              <select class="dropdown" name="categories" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" >
                <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [ngValue]="category">{{category}}</option>
              </select>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Manufactured By</div>
              <select class="dropdown" name="productionCompany" [(ngModel)]="selectedProductionCompany" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" >
                <option *ngFor="let company of companies" [ngValue]="company">{{company}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Materials</div>
              <select class="dropdown" name="finish" [(ngModel)]="selectedFinish" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" >
                <option *ngFor="let finish of finishes" [ngValue]="finish">{{finish}}</option>
              </select>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Transformer needed</div>
              <select class="dropdown" name="transformerNeeded" [(ngModel)]="selectedTransformerNeeded" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" >
                <option value="true" selected>Yes</option>
                <option value="false" >No</option>
              </select>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Power(W)</div>
              <input type="number"  name="power" [(ngModel)]="product.power" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>CCT(K)</div>
               <div fxLayout="row">
                <input type="number"  name="cct" [(ngModel)]="product.cct" #cct="ngModel" number (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" />
                <div class="validation-error-message"> <p *ngIf="cct.errors?.number" color:red>  CCT should be number</p></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>IK</div>
              <input type="number"  name="ik" [(ngModel)]="product.ik" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Index of protection</div>
              <input type="number"  name="ip" [(ngModel)]="product.ip" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Luminous</div>
              <input type="number"  name="luminous" [(ngModel)]="product.luminous" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Optic</div>
              <input type="number"  name="optic" [(ngModel)]="product.optic" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>CRI</div>
              <input type="number"  name="cri" [(ngModel)]="product.cri" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Light Source</div>
              <select class="dropdown" name="lightSource" [(ngModel)]="selectedLightSource" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" >
                <option *ngFor="let lightSource of lightSources" [ngValue]="formatStrings(lightSource)" >{{lightSource}}</option>
              </select>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Production country</div>
              <select class="dropdown" name="productionContry" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)" >
                <option *ngFor="let company of countries" [ngValue]="formatStrings(company)" >{{company}}</option>
              </select>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='control-btn-container'>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px">
          <button class="btn cancel" fxLayoutAlign="center center" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn save" fxLayoutAlign="center center" >Save</button>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </form>
    </div>
```

i use spring boot in the backend.

```html
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
    at y (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at Z (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:218)
    at t.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:365)
    at vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:521
    at t.invoke (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:365)
    at t.invoke (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at e.run (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781
    at t.invokeTask (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:365)
    at t.invokeTask (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at e.runTask (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at s (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at HTMLFormElement.invoke (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at y (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at Z (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:218)
    at t.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:365)
    at vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:521
    at t.invoke (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:365)
    at t.invoke (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at e.run (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781
    at t.invokeTask (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:365)
    at t.invokeTask (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at e.runTask (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at s (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at HTMLFormElement.invoke (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at y (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at p (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781
    at t.invokeTask (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:365)
    at t.invokeTask (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at e.runTask (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at s (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
    at HTMLFormElement.invoke (vendor.600ff6e….bundle.js:781)
```

Comment: Keep break points and debug..

Comment: In deployment mode there is no debuger